# Pass Annotation (To create Private load balancer ) to helm while installing ISTIO on Azure Kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes-helm, istio, azure-aks

[image]
Hi I am trying to install the ISTIO with helm on Azure kubernetes service. 
I wanted to pass below value for istio so that it will request a private ip on azure

```
annotations: {"service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal": "true"}
```

can some one let me know how i can pass this in the helm command so that it will override the annotations in values.yml ?

This is the helm command i am using but its gives me a error

helm install /opt/istio/istio-1.0.4/install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.serviceAnnotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create a private LB with the following helm command

helm install /opt/istio-1.0.4/install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system --set servicegraph.enabled=true --set servicegraph.enable=true --set tracing.enabled=true --set grafana.enabled=true --set kiali.enabled=true --set prometheus.enabled=true --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.serviceAnnotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"='"true"'